# pip --version takes time to return the first time but is fast afterwards

Tags: python, pip

I have noticed on fresh VM's that when I run `pip --version` in a bash shell, the first time takes around 20 seconds to return.  After that it returns very fast.  What is the reason for this?

Comment: Short answer: Caching

Comment: Where does it get cached and what is caching it?

Comment: Likely the OS is caching the files it called in RAM